# How to check and narrow a type with isNull instead of isNonNullable in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

I would like to universally type guard entities before returning them from an API. I want to make sure that anything that is `null | undefined` throws an `HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND` and thus I wanted to do something like this:

```
export const entityOr404 = <T>(entity: T | undefined): NonNullable<T> => {
  if (entity != null) {
    throw new HttpException('Not Found', HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND)
  }
  return entity
}
```

But in this case, TypeScript cannot understand that entity is NonNullable when returning (`Type 'T' is not assignable to type 'NonNullable<T>'.`). I also don't want to use the non-null assertion because I'd have to disable the eslint rule for this line. So I thought of doing something like this instead:

```
const isNonNullable = <T>(
  entity: T | null | undefined
): entity is NonNullable<T> => {
  return entity != null
}


export const entityOr404 = <T>(entity: T | undefined): NonNullable<T> => {
  if (!isNonNullable(entity)) {
    throw new HttpException('Not Found', HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND)
  }
  return entity
}
```

What I don't like about this solution is that I have to negate it and I think it would be more clear to have `isNull` instead of `!isNonNullable` and thus I'd like to write something like:

```
type Nullable = undefined | null
const isNull = (entity: unknown): entity is Nullable => {
  return entity == null
}
```

But then I'm of course back to TypeScript being confused and throwing `Type 'T' is not assignable to type 'NonNullable<T>'.` when trying to return the entity. Is there a way for me to express the `isNonNullable` as its opposite? Somehow let TypeScript know that if `!isNull(entity) then entity is NonNullable`?

Comment: Since you want to throw an error, I think it is more suitable here to use assertion function. See [this](https://tsplay.dev/WP74em) example

Answer (score 1):

An assertion is the way !

```
const isNonNullable = <T>(
  entity: T | null | undefined
): entity is NonNullable<T> => {
  return entity != null
}


function assertEntity<T,>(entity: T): asserts entity is NonNullable<T> {
  if (isNonNullable(entity != null)) {
    throw new Error('My Error')
  }
}

const entityOr404 = <T>(entity: T): NonNullable<T> => {
  assertEntity(entity)
  return entity
};

entityOr404(null) // never
entityOr404(5)    // number
entityOr404({})   // object
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=0&ssl=21&ssc=26&pln=15&pc=13#code/MYewdgzgLgBAlhAcuRBXANughgI3QUxgF4YAeAFQD4AKAKBhnzCjigE8AuGcmAHxjAZ0fGKjAATfADM4YfONoBKLkxbt4EGMjBpMuAhUrEjAb3owATviioLYRs1ZsYAQhKDMtAL61fUscAs4DBYEBD4FlAAoo7sFAA0NKpOXOTKIWERUJrJ6ghaKEL6%20IYwZgxwUjDUCNq62Hj41LnObgJCiopl5gxQABYWIADuAvgjURaDFtQA5ACyzhNTM4rmPj60oJCwLQDyFgAsAAwHxGRUzbGc3Ol1RY2lRKbmoeGRMWpsl5%20rDFY2dgcn28AG5fHtDidqB50F0APRw0YANwitAhxwO1AArPDEYIALY4VHoqEmLy4mAgHAAK3wgVoQA)